# How to add virtual printer on iOS programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, printing, uikit

I need to add to standard "print" view in iOS my "virtual printer" which will navigate to my application with sending content where it was called (e.g. email, safari)

Here is a video how it already works: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9gAzO-E33Q

How to implement it?

Thank you in advance.